How to write footers that say Page x of n for multiple worksheets in Python XlsxWriter
I have a python program that loops through a dataframe that contains multiple cases in it.
First I create a workbook like this:
        file_stream = io.BytesIO()
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_stream, engine='xlsxwriter')
        workbook = writer.book

I then iterate through a dataframe like this setting up page parameters and defining a footer:
        for index, row in case_df.iterrows():
            for column in case_df.columns:
                if row['Case No']!=current_case_no:
                    current_case_no=row['Case No']
                    footer=f'&C{agency} - Case No. {current_case_no}  Page &P of &N'
                    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(f'{current_case_no}')
                    worksheet.set_paper('Letter')
                    worksheet.set_margins(top=.5, bottom=.5, left=.5, right=.5)
                    worksheet.set_column(0, 15, 12) 
                    worksheet.set_default_row(13)
                    worksheet.set_footer(footer)

The code then writes lines of data to the worksheet and I finish up by closing the writer and converting the workbook to a PDF like this:
        writer.close()
        # RESET THE FILE STREAM TO THE BEGINNING
        file_stream.seek(0)
        pdf_stream = excel_to_pdf_stream(file_stream)

When I view the resulting PDF, it contains all of the worksheets as expected, but page numbering in the footer is off.  Instead of starting over at page 1 for each worksheet, it treats all of the worksheets as a single document so that by the time I get to the first page of the last case, it will say something like Page 74 of 80 instead of starting over at Page 1 of N.
How do I define a footer in xlsxwriter so that the page numbering starts over on each new worksheet.  I'm hoping not to have to count worksheets, lines, and pages and do my page numbering manually.

This doesn’t sound like an XlsxWriter issue because it only includes the Excel directive Page &P of &N in the file and doesn’t convert it to an actual page count. That is done by Excel at runtime. At a guess this is the PDF conversion issue (what are you using for that?). You could verify this yourself by checking the  XlsxWriter output in Excel to see if it is correct and also checking if there is any difference when converting a similar file, created ir saved in Excel, to PDF.

I use the xlwings module to convert from Excel to PDF.

def xl_to_pdf_stream(xl_stream):
    with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
        tmp_xl_path = 'tmp_xl.xlsx'
        with open(tmp_xl_path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(xl_stream.read())

        wb = app.books.open(tmp_xl_path)
        tmp_pdf_path = 'tmp_pdf.pdf'
        wb.to_pdf(tmp_pdf_path)
        wb.close()
        pdf_stream = io.BytesIO()
  
        with open(tmp_pdf_path, 'rb') as f:
            pdf_stream.write(f.read())

        os.remove(tmp_xl_path)
        os.remove(tmp_pdf_path)
        pdf_stream.seek(0)
        return pdf_stream

